# When baking with a world environment, black rectangles are showing up where they shouldn't be

Tags: texture-baking

I've set the metalic to zero on all objects, and can't figure out why it's baking those rectangles in the middle of my image. I understand it's black where the columns are, but in the main pathway and bottom, I don't see where it's coming from.
[image]

Comment: Probably has to do with all those arch copy's you have hidden in the viewport, but still enabled for renders - these will be included in the baking process. Luckily, since they're already part of their own collection, you can simply disable the collection (uncheck the box).

Comment: Maybe overlapping UV islands? What does it give if you unwrap and bake again?

Comment: Thank you Christopher!